# How do I create an instance of a form in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I’m working on a project for my C# class and the professor wants us to create an interface where we can select between 2 game projects we have created and run them. Basically he wants us to create an instance of the form and run it. These are 3 different projects in the same solution. I have tried looking all over google, YouTube, the book and our lectures, with no success. I was just wondering if anyone knew how to create an instance of a form, for example let’s say I need project1.form1. This is in Visual Studio using C#. He said we cannot just call the exe, and after emailing him he just left me with create an instance of the form then call either the show() or showDialog() method.

Edit: This is a windows form application, but one of the projects is using a wpf project.

Comment: `var form = new Form()`

Comment: How would it know which project and form though? Would I call var form = new Form1();? Or would I assign the form.text = “form1”?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, we may have, due to a lack of planning, named every form form1. Only in my first year of school, so I’m still learning about issues like this and avoiding them in the future.

Comment: Meda's comment isn't particularly helpful..

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks, yours is even less helpful

Comment: @meda I wasn't talking to you

Answer (score 1):

So you say you have 3 projects, one of which is a WPF but it isn't immediately clear which one. These projects are all in the same solution and you've called all the forms "Form1".

Honestly, I'd rectify that problem now; newbies either don't know or don't care to name their classes and variables well but it's one of the most important things you can do to make your program understandable and easy to write. The opposite of naming things well is called obfuscation, a process that deliberately turns variable names into incomprehensible garbage to make it deliberately difficult to understand the program (resist attempts to decompile it). Calling your form "GameForm" or "InventoryForm" or "MapForm" is much better than "Form"1, "Form2", "Form3"… then having to remember or look up that it's "Form3" that is the map form, and that it's "Button27" to zoom in but "Button13" to zoom out

It's easy to do too, so no excuses; you click on the word Form1 anywhere you can see it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>. The word glows green and then you type a new name and press return, and you see it change everywhere

If you're unwilling to do this then you have to refer to the form by its namespace or give it an alias. If you've used the same namespace then you have a real problem. Honestly; take 5 seconds out to rename the form

Once that's done you need to know about references and usings

---

All your projects are in the same solution, which is great because it means you can reference one from another. In the project hmthat must make the new form from the other right click the References node under the project node in solution explorer and choose Add Reference

In the window that appears, choose Project on the left (you can add different kinds of references, ie to DLL files on disk, to stuff Microsoft provide as part of .net, to other projects you wrote) and then pick the project(s) this project will need to use. You only need to do this for "the main project that needs to use the other project" - try to avoid creating situations where projects depend on each other

This now means that the main project knows about the other project so you can refer to its classes in code by their full names (including their namespaces) which is what you might have to do if you don't rename your form. Suppose your `MapForm` is in the `GameNavigationScreens` namespace:

```
namespace GameNavigationScreens {
  public class MapForm: Form { ... }
}
```

You can make it like:

```
var f = new GameNavigationScreens.MapForm();
```

Or you can import every class inside `GameNavigationScreens` so you can remove the namespace  from the code:

```
using GameNavigationScreens;

...

var f = new GameNavigationScreens.MapForm();
```

This is the part you can't do if you have two classes named the same, have referenced both their projects and using'd both their namespaces:

```
using GameNavigationScreens;
using GameInventoryScreens;

...

var f = new Form1(); //but which Form1? 

//if you don't rename, you'll still have to specify
var f = new GameNavigationScreens.Form1();
var g = new GameInventoryScreens.Form1();
```

And just looking at the code you have to remember that `Form1` is the map form and `Form1` is the knapsack form. Or was it the shop form? Even if you can remember now, you won't in 3 months.